# joint convergence in distribution of three random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose
$$(U_n,V_n)\overset{d}{\to}(U,h (U)) $$
for some random variable $U $. 
If also
$$(U_n,W_n)\overset{d}{\to}(U, g (U))$$
can I then conclude that
$$(U_n, V_n, W_n)\overset{d}{\to}(U,h (U), g (U)) ?$$

I know that in general $(U_n,V_n)\overset{d}{\to}(U,V)$ and $(V_n,W_n)\overset{d}{\to}(V,W)$ does not imply that they converge jointly as well, but in this case, these random variables are very dependent, so my intuition tells me that they should also converge jointly.

Comment: IOW, you assume that $(U_n,V_n)\overset{d}{\to}(U,g(U))$ and that $(U_n,W_n)\overset{d}{\to}(U,h(U))$ and you are asking whether this implies that $(U_n,V_n,W_n)\overset{d}{\to}(U,g(U),h(U))$.

Comment: yes, indeed, that is a better formulation of the question.